# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Beta 8 - Do I have to use kestrel with IIS Express?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel-http-server

Working with ASP.NET 5 MVC 6, Beta 8.   Using IIS Express in a local dev windows 10 environment with IE Edge as my browser, but I noticed that IIS Express won't server the page without have a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel in my project.

I thought Kestrel was the cross platform web server and not necessarily what you needed to work with IIS Express, so can someone explain why the reference is needed now?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft made changes to the hosting model, because having two different hosting models for IIS introduced inconsistencies.

> Hosting ASP.NET 5 applications in IIS will now be achieved using the
>   IIS HttpPlatformHandler configured to forward through to the ASP.NET 5
>   Kestrel server. The HttpPlatformHandler is a native IIS module that
>   needs to be installed by an administrator on the server running IIS.

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/10/15/announcing-availability-of-asp-net-5-beta8.aspx) describes it further under the headline **Changes to IIS Hosting Model**.